# MySql Join performance vs Where + in

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have encountered a problem when joining two tables. One large table with 140M rows and the other is small table with 100 rows while joining on the primary key.

The two tables are:

```
DataTable 
{
    Date timestamp,
    Hash varchar(20),
    Type varchar(20),
    Purchases int,
    Store varchar(20),
    Primary key (Date, Hash)
}
```

DataTable is a very big table with 140M rows

```
ProductTable
{
    Hash varchar(20),
    Name varchar(20),
    Primary key (Hash)
}
```

ProductTable is small table with only 100 rows

I ran two separate queries

```
Select sum(DataTable.Purchases),DataTable.Store 
from DataTable 
   Join  ProductTable on ProductTable.Hash = DataTable.Hash  
   Where Type =2
   and Date<='2015-12-31'
   and Date>='2015-1-1'
group by DataTable.Store
```

This took very long time (actually never ends). When running explain this showed that it processed almost the half of table. As shown in this explain:

```
select_type |table       |type    |possible_keys|key     | key_len | ref               |rows  |Extra       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Simple      |DataTable   |All     |Date, Hash   |Null    | Null    | Null              |7*10^7|using where
Simlpe      |ProductTable| eq_ref |PRIMARY       PRIMARY | 386     | ProductTable.Hash |   1 | Using where |
```

Just for kicks I took all the relevant hashes from the ProductTable and put them in a Where In clause. Like the following:

```
Select sum(DataTable.Purchases),DataTable.Store
   From DataTable 
   Where DataTable.Hash in ("1ha84u","1ha850","1ha851",...,"1hl931")
   Type =2
   and DataTable.Date<='2015-12-31'
   and DataTable.Date>='2015-12-1'
   group by DataTable.Store
```

This resulted in much better performance - taking less than 2 seconds and scanning less rows.

```
select_type |table       |type    |possible_keys|key           | key_len | ref |rows |Extra |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Simple      |DataTable   |range   |Date, Hash   |Date, Hash    | 62      | Null|11097|using where
```

I do not understand why the Primary key wasn't used for the first query and why the second one resulted in much better performance.

I have made sure that the result was not cached by MySql between runs.

Comment: Can you pls run an explain on the 1st query, just this time include a force index hint on date, hash index? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html

Comment: They are different queries with different results. The first one will show all the rows that match the 3 where clausules, adding to de `Datatable` the info of the `ProductTable`. The second one just shows up the info of the `Datatable` that matchs that `Hash` list and the other where clausules.

Comment: Btw, the 2nd query is a lot faster, since it uses index to select data from the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add index (Hash, Date) to DataTable

Comment: DataTable has primary key (Date, Hash). Why adding index (Hash, Date) will make the different?